# Storing ajax response data into array and compare it to the last values

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I am stuck with these. I want to create a function to be run every 4secs. Now My function will get all the queue_id from my database and store it in array again and again, after storing it, i will compare it again and again every 4 secs, if there are changes , then i will do something.

Example execution : If my database response with queue_id's: 1,2,3,4,5 then i will store these data from an array. After storing it, i will query again evry 4 seconds if it returns 1,2,4,5 or 1,2,3,5 i will do something, but if it returns thesame like 1,2,3,4,5 then i will not do something.

I have no idea how to store or create array in javascript . Please help me:

```
function check_getqueue(clinicID, userID) {
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/checkingUpdates/"+clinicID+"/"+userID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        var tmpCountQ = data[i]['queue_id'];
      };

      if (tmpCountQ < lastcountQueue) { 

      }
      lastcountQueue = tmpCountQ;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: looks like `data` is already an array ... use `x = data` to put it in another variable (x in this case) if you must ...

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you for your comment sir, how can i store the data response into array, and compare it's values from previous to new, because i am making this function run every 4 secs.

Comment: store: like I just said - compare, that's javascript 101 stuff

Comment: One approach I can think of is, store values from the database into hidden field somewhere (delimiter separated string format) and every time your ajax code will compare both hidden field values with database values and at the end you will update hidden field value with latest values from the database.

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar i dont want to add another table for this situation sir, because i only want is to store all the queue_id's if it gives me something like: 1,2,3,4,5 then the next query will be 1,2,3,4 then i'll refresh the div, and again if it gives me 1,2,4,5 i will refresh the div again everytime there was change values in queue_id from database.

Answer (score 0):

Use push, and declare the array outside the ajax request. now all working

```
function check_getqueue(clinicID, userID) {
  var tmpCountQ = [];
  var lastCon = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/checkingUpdates/"+clinicID+"/"+userID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        tmpCountQ.push(data[i]['queue_id']);
      };
      if(typeof lastCon[0] != "undefined")
      {
        for(j=0;j < tmpCountQ.length;j++)
        {
          if(tmpCountQ[j] != lastCon[j])
          {
            lastCon[j] = tmpCountQ[j];
          } 
        }
      }
      else
      {
       lastCon = tmpCountQ;
      }

      console.log(tmpCountQ);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir, can you add it with these please: how can i store the data response into array, and compare it's values from previous to new, because i am making this function run every 4 secs

Comment: what is the json url? can you post?

Comment: what do you mean by JSON URL SIR. Its already there. the siteurl+.. etc.

Comment: I want to get the json object, to write you function checking values

Comment: it gives me a result of these sir: [{"queue_id":"1"},{"queue_id":"3"}]

Comment: there is no need for sorting it because in my query i make it asc.

Comment: check my answer, that what you need?

Comment: @ hello sir where would i insert my another code if the temp array is not equal with the new data response

Comment: i will call another function if the condition is acquired. can you please put 
//code here

Comment: `if(tmpCountQ[j] != lastCon[j])
          {
            YourFunction();
            lastCon[j] = tmpCountQ[j];
          }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135030/discussion-between-jc-john-and-l-vadim).

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the lastly received set of ids and compare them with the new ones. When a difference found, call your doSomething() and update the record for next run.

To get things faster you can first check the lengths. More info in the comment blocks below.

```
var previousQueueIDs = [];

function doSomething() {
  // do something
  // ...
  // set timer for the next run
  setTimeout(check_getqueue, 4000);
}

function check_getqueue(clinicID, userID) {
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/checkingUpdates/"+clinicID+"/"+userID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      var queueIDs = [];
      if(previousQueueIDs.length != data.length) {
        previousQueueIDs = queueIDs;
        return doSomething();
      }
      // length didn't change, so check further
      // create new array for the current values
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        queueIDs.push(+data[i]['queue_id']);
      };

      // sort them for faster comparison
      queueIDs.sort( function(a,b) {
        return a-b;
      });

      // check one by one and exit to run doSomething
      // as soon as the first difference found
      for(var i=0; i<queueIDs.length; i++) {
        if(queueIDs[i] != previousQueueIDs[i]) {
          previousQueueIDs = queueIDs;
          return doSOmething();
        }
      }
      // no difference this time, just set timer for the next run
      setTimeout(check_getqueue, 4000);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: there is no need for sorting it, because in my query i made it already ascending order